# While loop not cycling back to the beginning

Tags: python

I'm doing the CS50 Python path. For this exercise, I'm tasked with creating a Coke machine that will ask the user for an amount in coins to put in the machine. If the amount of coins is less than the total which is set at 50, it is then supposed to say "Amount due:" and then cycle back through the code.

For the if statement, I wanted to make it so that if the amount of coins put in is greater than the total, it then prints out "Change due:" along with the amount of change that is due back to the user. The problem comes in is that the program gives the amount due, however, it will not cycle back through and instead prints out the amount due plus the print statement in the elif.

My code:

```
def main():

    machine()

def machine():
    total = 50
    print("Total amount:", total)
    coin = int(input("Insert coin: "))

    while coin < total:
        total = total - coin
        print("Amount due:", total)

        if coin > total:
            total = coin - total
            print("Change due: ",total)

        elif coin == total:
            print("Thank you for your money!")
main()
```

The output:

[image: Image of output in console]

I tried adding a continue as well as a break and nothing helped.

Comment: The second iteration `count < total` would be `25 < 25`. 25 is not less than 25 so the while loop exits. I think you want `<=` instead. That being said, I'm not really following what you are trying to do down in that `if/elif` block so likely you are going to run into more issues once that is solved.

Comment: You want to either add coins into a sum to equal total or subtract coins from total to equal zero. You have elements of both approaches here, and it's making it really confusing to figure out what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through your code on paper and see what's happening

1. Set `total` to `50`
2. Set `coin` to `25`
3. While `coin` (`25`) < `total` (`50`) [true]
4. Subtract `coin`(`25`) from `total` (`25`) [`total` = `25`]
5. if `coin`(`25`) > `total` (`25`) [false]
6. elif `coin`(`25`) == `total` (`25`) [true]
7. print
8. test loop case: While `coin`(`25`) < `total`(`25`) [false]
9. break loop

Now this is not the behaviour you want, that's becuase you dont want to be comparing `total` to `coin`, you want to be comparing `total` to `0`

```
while total > 0:
    total = total - coin
    print("Amount due:", total)

    if total < 0:
        total = coin - total
        print("Change due: ",total)

    elif total = 0:
        print("Thank you for your money!")
```

If you want to be able to specify diffent money values each time, you need to include the "taking input" stage in your loop

```
coin = 0
while total > 0:
    coin = int(input("Insert coin: "))
    total = total - coin
    print("Amount due:", total)

    if total < 0:
        total = coin - total
        print("Change due: ",total)

    elif total = 0:
        print("Thank you for your money!")
```

Otherwise the value of it will not change each loop and it will keep subtracting whatever you intially put there over and over

Answer (score -1):

When you used while loop you changed the value of total from 50 to 35 hence the value of coin and total gets same and the elif block is executed. I don't think using while is a good idea and the code can just be rewritten as below:

```
        if coin < total:
            total = total - coin
            print("Amount due:", total)

        elif coin > total:
            total = coin - total
            print("Change due: ",total)

        else:
            print("Thank you for your money!
```

Comment: This will not solve op's problem, as they want to simulate a transaction, in your solution providing less than the required amount would simply state the remaining amount due and terminate. (also 50 - 25 is 25, not 35)